# web3 js eth.contract equivalent in PHP

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, json-rpc, php

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://blahblah.com:8545"));
var token = web3.eth.contract(ABI).at("x0x_contract_address")
```

How would this be done in PHP?

For example with the ethereum.php library I use I can do things like this:

```
$data = new Ethereum_Transaction($users_eth_address, "x0_eth_address, $gas, $gasPrice, $hex_balance);
$result = $ethereum->eth_sendTransaction($data);
```

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: I basically had to convert all my PHP to js / node.js to get it to work using web3js. Then I run the node as a cron on a non web accessible page because of the personal unlockaccount password and the password to the RPC can't be visible to the public.

Comment: Sweet, it might be worth answering your own question then. I’d say people would be interested in the details of how you did that!

Answer (score 1):

btelle/ethereum-php is incomplete and outdated. Last commit is from 2015.

You might use [digitaldonkey/ethereum-php](https://github.com/digitaldonkey/ethereum-php)

```
// The json file "$fileName" used is what you get when you compile a contract with Truffle.

$ContractMeta = json_decode(file_get_contents($fileName));
$contract = new SmartContract(
  $ContractMeta->abi,
  $ContractMeta->networks->{NETWORK_ID}->address,
  new Ethereum(SERVER_URL)
);
$someBytes = new EthBytes('34537ce3a455db6b')
$x = $contract->myContractMethod();
echo $x->val()
```

Answer (score -1):

According to [the repository](https://github.com/btelle/ethereum-php)

```
// include the class file
require 'ethereum.php';

// create a new object
$ethereum = new Ethereum('127.0.0.1', 8545);

// do your thing
echo $ethereum->net_version();
```

This will allow you to connect to a local Geth instance on your machine listening on port `8545`.

For accessing a contract please refer to the [`test.php`](https://github.com/btelle/ethereum-php/blob/master/test/test.php) file that includes more examples of how to make use of the functions available to you.

You may find the documentation for the [JSON RPC API](https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/rpc.html) particularly useful here. This is because the `ethereum.php` project is essentially just a wrapper around the Ethereum implementation running at `localhost:8545`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm already using this via my send transaction php example in my question post. I'm asking specifically for the php equivalent of var token = web3.eth.contract(ABI).at("x0x_contract_address") so I can access the token to transfer. I've tried $ethereum->eth_contract(ABI)->at('x0_contract address')

Comment: the `at(address)` function does not correspond to a particular JSON RPC API. Therefore you'll not see an equivalent function in the `ethereum.php` project. `at(address)`  is called to get access to existing contract on a blockchain. Under the hood, when you create a new Contract. Web3 is just invoking standard JSON RPC functions to like `eth_sendTransaction`. You'll not get as "clean" of an api with the php wrapper like you do with Web3js.

Comment: This library is totally outdated.

Comment: At the time of answering this question it wasn’t.

Comment: It's outdated since 2015 ;)